Left bar outside of text area
I'd like to add a vertical side bar on the margin of some text, such as the blue one in the following pic:

So far I've used the leftbar environment, but not only it makes the bar inside the margins, but as a result it also messes up with the overall spacing:

Here's a snippet of what I'm using right now:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\title{Test}
\author{Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{leftbar}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{leftbar}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}

and here's the result:

I need an environment which does this instead:

Can you help me?
(Edit: added code).

Please post full MWE, from \documentclass to \end{document}

@MadyYuvi Done!

Have a look at the tcolorbox package. It has an option for oversized boxes

I've created a new environment "splleftbar", and the MWE is:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\usepackage{showframe}

\title{Test}
\author{Test}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{splleftbar}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{\hspace{-\parindent}\vrule width3pt\hspace{13pt}}%
  \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}%
\makeatother

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{splleftbar}%
    \lipsum[2]
\end{splleftbar}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}


tcolorbox and mdframed are the other options

Can I remove the default indentation on the highlighted text so that it can still be on the same paragraph of the text before it?

@ncant It depends on your wish :-)
